# httpBackend expect request only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, httpbackend

After a bit of trial and error I finally managed to get Jasmine to inject a mock Angular service and also provide `$httpBackend` in the same suite:

```
describe('services.system', function () {

    var httpBackend, nodeService;

    beforeEach(module('services.system'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.factory('authService', function() { return mockAuthService; });
        });

        inject(function(_nodeService_, $httpBackend) {
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
            nodeService = _nodeService_;
        });
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    describe('version', function () {
        it('should return the current version', function () {
            httpBackend.expectGET('/service/version').respond(200, { version: "1.2.3"});

            var done = false;
            runs(function() {
                nodeService.getProductInfo().then(function (info) {
                    expect(info.version).toEqual('1.2.3');
                    done = true;
                }, function(error) {
                    expect("test received error: " + error).toFail();
                    done = true;
                });

                httpBackend.flush();
            });

            waitsFor(function(){
                return done;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I now want to write a test that expects a GET only once, two consecutive calls should return a cached response and not make another request to the server. With spies it looks like you can usually do this by asserting `myObj.calls.count()`.

How might I verify that the HTTP request has only been invoked once?

Comment: If caching is not something that you have implemented, but is part of framework, then no point testing it. No point testing the framework.

Comment: Good point. I am storing the result in a variable, so the next call to getProductInfo() should be fetching from memory rather than performing another HTTP request.

Comment: `expectGET` has to be setup for each request I believe. So if you have only on `expectGET` in your test, and the test passes, there was only one request made.